# Can I use file_get_contents to load css?

Tags: php, html, css

Instead of this:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css_file.css" />
</head>
```

I want to do this:

```
<head>
    <style><?php file_get_contents("css_file.css");?></style>
</head>
```

For some reason though, the text shows up in the doc but the style is not applied. This is a two part question:

1. Why is this not working?
2. Is this a bad idea to do this?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to echo it out too?
    <?php echo file_get_contents("css_file.css");?>

Comment: About your second question, it would mean loading the source css in every file you load. Seems like a waste.

Comment: 2. yes it is a bad idea, it wont be cached. you will slow things down and use more bandwidth on your server and the clients end

Comment: Is there a real benefit to use this syntax? you are losing css files caching ...

Comment: Well...I wanted to use variables by using `<?php echo file_get_contents("css_file_css.php");?>` but before doing that I just tried .css and that didn't even work. I don't like keeping css files in a different folder on a different sheet. You're telling me it doesn't cache what is between style tags?

Comment: I know this question is pretty old, but you also can include .php file in echoed style tags, and print all the styles with variables in that php file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question was posted when I was a beginning developer. I didn't know about Sass and other easier and better ways to achieve variables in CSS. I also didn't know about browser caching.

Jeremy Karlsson answered the question in a comment. `file_get_contents` requires `echo`.

Answer (score 4):

This does what you'd like todo, output will be your css file, use something like [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) if you need to have more readable content, you might want to add new lines for example, before and after `{` `}`, I tested both without preg_replace and the examples are working well with a simple css file, I did not test it with complex css files but it should work as well, I kindly ask to try it with your css files. I hope it will help you into the right direction...

```
<?php
$css_File = file_get_contents("css_file.css"); // Can use single quot as well...
echo '<style type="text/css">' . $css_File . '</style>'; // All php echo example
?>
```

OR much better example, I think this could be what you want:

```
<?php $css_File = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/css_file.css'); ?>
<style type="text/css"><?php echo $css_File; ?></style><!--// your request example //-->
```

Answer (score 2):

why not use

```
include("css_file.css");
```

@edit
Also if you are including css file make sure to echo style tags around it